# Have there been any anime with actual product placement?

Tags: anime-production, steins-gate

In Steins;Gate, Dr. Pepper is mentioned several times as the "An Intellectual Drink, For The Chosen Ones".

[image: Dk Pepper]

I've seen a lot of other shows that have stores or products with similar names to the real-life brand, so that the producers can avoid copyright issues.

[image: Hescafe]
[image: WcDonalds]

Even though the inclusion of Dr.Pepper wasn't asked for by the Dr.Pepper company, after the release of Steins;Gate the sales in Japan for Dr.Pepper shot up. [ref](http://kotaku.com/5791129/is-japan-ready-to-stop-ignoring-dr-pepper).

Have there been any anime where a company has paid for their product to be included in the show?

Comment: Notice it's not actually "Dr. Pepper", but rather, "Dk. Pepper".

Comment: [TVTropes have a list](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ProductPlacement/AnimeAndManga)

Comment: @キルア It is in the anime, but in the original visual novel it's actually "Dr Pepper": http://i.stack.imgur.com/dXSbE.jpg

Comment: Hey guys what about manga? Is it the same? I saw dr pepper at oyasumi punpun manga.

Comment: @snailplane I remember when I play the VN it was "Dr People" instead of "Dr Pepper". I found a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/8j3aojJ.jpg ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/steinsgate/comments/577l4n/who_started_drinking_dr_pepper_because_of/d8po05s/))

Comment: @ZhuoyunWei Interesting!  Must have been changed for a translation, or a later version.  My screen shot is from the original Japanese Windows version.

Comment: @snailplane Ah I played the Steam version with official English translation. Looks like they modified the CG during the i18n.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes. Sometimes it's a sort of "exchange" of product placement - the anime will show the brand in the show, and the brand will put something about the show on its products for a certain timeframe.

## Code Geass: Pizza Hut

[image: Code Geass scene with Pizza Hut box] [image: Real life Pizza Hut box with Code Geass advertisement]

## Rebuild of Evangelion

[image: Scene with Doritos bags] [image: Real life Dorito bags with Evangelion characters]

## Tiger & Bunny: Various

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm sure there are more examples but these are just a few.

Comment: I would like to add that the Pizza Hut references are edited out of the English localized version of Code Geass, in the Japanese version you can see the Pizza Hut logo clearly when the Pizza is being delivers to C.C, however in the english version either the logo has been totally removed or just the text with hat part made a bot more bluring

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the other answers...

The first episode of the new *Ghost in the Shell: ARISE* series features various shots of various ads for the Surface tablet and the device itself.

[image: Surface-desu]

The *Evangelion* Rebuild films have had long lingering shots of a Lawson's convenience store. Also, Misato’s fridge is stocked with Kirin beer.

[image: Bi-ruuuuuu]

In *Macross Frontier* movie, Ranka and Alto go into a FamilyMart convenience store as a plot point...

[image: Why are there ads in my plot?!]

Comment: Ranka also has a CM song for Family Mart!

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Well, there's [Tiger & Bunny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%26_Bunny) which plastered product placement to the extreme of its real-life sponsors:

> Each of the city's most famous superheroes work for a sponsor company and their uniforms also contain advertising for real-life companies.

The show features "sponsored" super heroes who fight crime, with their sponsors plastered all over them like NASCAR, and in some cases, even doing in-show commercials for the actual product (e.g. Pepsi). Some of these in-show sponsors were actually sponsors of the show. The old Tiger & Bunny website (it's since been changed) listed all of their sponsors which had product placement: [via archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20110902083004/http://www.tigerandbunny.net/link/index.html).

[image]

I don't know if these companies actually went to the producers to pay for advertising spots within the show. It's probably more likely that it was a two-way street, working much like how anime get made in general, where the producers/studio will look for sponsors with an idea, and a contract and agreement is made. So these companies went into it knowing how their product would be placed in the show.

When the show was adapted into a manga, all of the product placement was removed (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Here. This one's from Nichijou.

And yes, it's the real thing as is featured in the credit: (0:59 in [the ending 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pue606bayV4))

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Full Metal Panic has product placements of Budweiser and Heineken.

Comment: There's also "Pizza But" in TSR, "Bocari Sweat" in the original series.  Heineken was "Heibeken" beer. But somehow Budweiser remained unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Great Teacher Onizuka features a Vaio laptop:

[image: Great Teacher Onizuka: Sony Vaio]

There are also Infiniti and Nissan placements in Ghost in the Shell: Arise

Answer (score 2):

The Katsuhiro Otomo-designed [Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Project) OAV series is a particularly fun viewing experience for product placement, since it came into being as part of a Nissin Cup Noodles promotional campaign.  In it, remnants of humanity live in a lunar colony where -- incidentally and inexplicably -- Nissin Cup Noodles are a primary food source.