# Parody brand names in anime

Tags: code-geass, darker-than-black

Why do anime use parody brand names in their series, and what benefit do anime like Code Geass and Darker than Black get when they use original brand names like Pizza Hut? Do they get paid for promoting the brand? If not, so they have to pay the company for copyrights? What benefit do the anime/manga artists get in the end?

Comment: You might like to read http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/have-there-been-any-anime-with-actual-product-placement and http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6432/are-real-life-products-always-connected-to-the-show-they-have-on-their-packaging

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko. Thanks. That was a good reference.