# Is Cheese-kun real?

Tags: culture, code-geass, japan

In Code Geass, particularly in the original Japanese version, we can see there was something like a product placement exchanged (as shown in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4259/1587)) between the series and Pizza Hut.

[image: Code Geass scene with Pizza Hut box] 
[image: Real life Pizza Hut box with Code Geass advertisement]

Later in the series, C.C. starts having stickers and a giant plush of what appears to be Pizza Hut's mascot, named Cheese-kun.

[image: stickers and figures]
[image: shipped from Pizza Hut]

Now, back when Code Geass first appeared in the west, I did not notice Pizza Hut having anything like Cheese-kun in Australia, but then again it appears there was an attempt to remove Pizza Hut references from the series when it was localized in the west.

So I am wondering, does Cheese-kun exist in Japan? If so, did it exist before or after Code Geass? Who created it, the author of Code Geass or Pizza Hut? And does it still represent Pizza Hut now?

Comment: I do recall Cheese-Kun being the official mascot of pizza hut Japan around 2008/2009.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So I am wondering, does Cheese-kun exist in Japan? If so, did it exist before or after Code Geass?

Yes, Cheese-kun exists IRL and predates Code Geass. See, for example, [this 13 Aug 2006 Wayback Machine snapshot of a page on Pizza Hut's Japanese website](http://web.archive.org/web/20060813162715/http://www.pizzahut.jp/club/), which includes images of Cheese-kun.

> And does it still represent Pizza Hut now?

The [/pizzahut.japan Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pizzahut.japan/) (Pizza Hut's official page for Japan) made [a post that includes a picture of Cheese-kun](https://www.facebook.com/pizzahut.japan/posts/982532425117558) just a few hours ago, so I'm going to assume yes.