# Who is Prince of Darkness?

Tags: bleach

When Ichigo was using Hiyori Sarugaki's workout machine, there is some banter with the Visored such as Kensei Muguruma complaining about Lisa Yadoumaru reading swimsuit magazines instead of watching Ichigo.

At one point, Roujuurou Ootoribashi asks Love Aikawa if he has heard the new *Prince of Darkness* CD that has just come out, who then replies if he had read the latest issue of Shounen Jump.

Now I get why Shounen Jump is featured because the Bleach manga is serialized in it, but I am wondering, is Prince of Darkness a real life band? If so, then what is their connection to Bleach? Is it just merely [product placement](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/have-there-been-any-anime-with-actual-product-placement)?

NOTE: this is in the English Dub.

Answer (score 2):

It is most certainly a reference to Ozzy Osbourne. [Ozzy Osbourne - Prince of Darkness](https://www.discogs.com/Ozzy-Osbourne-Prince-Of-Darkness/release/2377565).

As for why, this is what I found in  [The Bleach Breakdown: The Unofficial Guide
*by Issei Handa, Walt Wyman*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/544330.The_Bleach_Breakdown) in the Character Breakdown Section, for **Rose**, emhasis mine.

> ***Rose***
>   Long, Blond, wavy hair and seventies hard rock clothes. Seems like a narcissist, and maybe gay. Calls Rabu "Love" (he pronounces it "Ravu", which is one step closer than the typical Japanese pronunciation, "Rabu"). Wishes Rabu would let him read his Shonen Jump. More calm and easy-going than most of the Vizards. He plays the guitar. **At one point he mentions "Prince of Darkness's new Album." It can be surmised that he is named after Ozzy Osbourne's legendary first guitarist Randy Rose. Prince of Darkness is an Ozzy Osbourne album.**

Thus I consider it mostly an easter Egg about the name Rose.

Answer (score 0):

The only "Prince of Darkness" I can think of (in relation to music) would be Ozzy Osbourne.  Now, I couldn't say for certain that this is who they were referencing, as Japan could have their own "Prince of Darkness," but Ozzy would be a good guess.