# Who/what is Gamers and what is their connection to the Love Live series?

Tags: love-live

In the first episode of *Love Live! School Idol Project* season 2, the girls went to what I assume is an arcade where the front sign says Gamers. When watching the ED for episode 2, I noticed this same logo appear in the credits (this is the localized version released by NISA).

I am wondering who/what is Gamers and what is their connection to the *Love Live* series? Is it just a [product placement](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/4257/1587) deal with the anime or has it got something to do with the real life idol group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gamers is a hobby shop specializing in anime, manga, games and their related merchandises.

[image: Akihabara GAMERS]

<sup>AKIHABARA GAMERS - Image courtesy of [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Akiba_games4.jpg#/media/File:Akiba_games4.jpg)</sup>

Apparently, Gamers has appeared many times on *Love Live!* anime. According to [NineColors.com (Japanese)](http://nine-colors.com/), a site that lists real-life places used in the anime:

- [Season 1, Episode 3](http://nine-colors.com/003_anim1/1_03_anim/) (different font/logo)

  [image: LL-Gamers old] [image: Gamers 1]
- [Season 1, Episode 6](http://nine-colors.com/003_anim1/1_06_anim/)
- [Season 1, Episode 9](http://nine-colors.com/003_anim1/1_09_anim/) (the first episode with proper font/logo)

  [image: LL-Gamers new] [image: Gamers 2]
- [Season 1, Episode 13](http://nine-colors.com/003_anim1/1_13_anim/)
- [Season 2, Episode 1](http://nine-colors.com/004_anim2/2_01_anim/)
- [Season 2, Episode 3](http://nine-colors.com/004_anim2/2_03_anim/)
- [Season 2, Episode 13](http://nine-colors.com/004_anim2/2_13_anim/)

When comparing to other shops, only Gamers have its original name shown with proper logo while others were changed. This gives a big hint that it's a product placement deal.

However, Gamers itself has done some tie-ups/collaborations with *Love Live!* series itself. Some examples are bonus merchandise for *Love Live!* products (anime Blu-Ray, CD singles).

According to [オタクの戯言's HatenaBlog (Japanese)](http://aniota-alvarado.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/10/03/081634), there's also a special booth for "μ's Final Love Live!", displaying the outfit used on "SUNNY DAY SONG" performance and other things like visitors' comment, merchandises, all released singles and albums, and posters.

[image: booth in front of the shop] [image: BD/DVD racks]

Moving to ***Love Live! Sunshine!!***, there's Gamers Museum, displaying a comment board (separated into text only/with picture), Aquors scene in the anime, introduction to their songs, and casts' signature.

[image: Love Live! Sunshine!! Museum at Gamers] [image: comment board with picture]

Last but not least are *Love Live! Sunshine!!* special pages on [Gamers (Japanese)](https://www.gamers.co.jp/special/55597/) and [Gamers onlineshop (Japanese)](https://www.gamers-onlineshop.jp/corner/cc/lovelive_sunshine/cd/96/) website.