# What is this Doc Tear Popper MAGES is looking for?

Tags: hyperdimension-neptunia

in *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth*, MAGES asks the party if they know were she can find Doc Tear Popper. what exactly is it?

Comment: She also calls it Doc Pop on occasion

Answer (score 1):

Doc Tear Popper is a drink and a play on the name Dr. Pepper.

the character MAGES, like other human characters in the series, represents a real world games company, in this case [株式会社MAGES](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAGES.). one of the known games which ties into MAGES's own appearance is [Steins;Gate](https://vndb.org/v2002) which in the anime had product placement featuring the drink Dr. Pepper

[image: Doctor Pepper!] [image: It's an intellectual drink for the chosen ones!]

I don't know however wether the obscuring of the name is some legal thing as [Code Geass had it's Pizza Hut product placement removed in the English Release](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/have-there-been-any-anime-with-actual-product-placement#comment19067_4259) or if it's a joke like Vert's overheating in the original game begin a joke on the X-Box 360's initial cooling problems